# rjxjs handle network errors from socket.io-client

Tags: socket.io, rxjs, ngrx

I use rxjs and socket.io client.
Id like to solve this problem.

1. socket is connected
2. user send data
3. socket is having any network error during delivery
4. delivery is faled
5. socket throw error to user

Here is my code. how to handle network errors indise Observable?

```
   private sendData(data: any, event: SOCKET_EVENTS): Observable<any> {   
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
      this.socket
        .emit(event, data, function(responseData: Result<any>) {
          console.log("Data sended", responseData);
          if (responseData.success === true) {
            observer.next(responseData.data);
            observer.complete();
          } else {
            console.error(" this.socketData not sended", responseData);
            observer.error(data);
          }
        })
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle errors globaly using event [error](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98error%E2%80%99) or something else. For every single emit you can use [acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements). Anyway, procedure which handle errors should be more complex. For example:

```
private sendData(data: any, event: SOCKET_EVENTS): Observable<any> {   
return new Observable<any>(observer => {
  // set timeout before call error
  let errorTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      console.error(" this.socketData not sended");
      observer.error();
  }, 5000);

  this.socket
    .emit(event, data, (responseData: Result<any>) => {
      console.log("Data sended", responseData);
        observer.next(responseData.data);
        observer.complete();

        // reset timer
        clearTimeout(errorTimeout);
    })
 });
```

}

We wait 5 seconds for response with acknowledgement. Also you should add logic to handle global errors.

Comment: What can u say about this solution :  1) before sending check socket satus, if disconnected throwError 2) add  once('disconnected') to socket.emit().  Code here  https://pastebin.com/kvkkMgmV